# Email friend redirect to login page for guest user. how to allowed them to email without login?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-page

I am using Magento 1.9 On product page when user click on email friend link redirect to login if not logged in. I want to allow them to email friend without login. is it possible? how can i achieve this

Comment: There is setting in admin

Comment: @Kul where can i find it?

Comment: sorry i am new. i am not aware of all functions

Comment: i have posted answer please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In admin there is option to make allowed email to friend for guest user. you can enable this from `system->configurations->Catalog->Email to a friend`

here you can see field  `Allow for Guests`. make it `Yes`.